# How to generate a data dictionary with the help of existing logical Data model/Physical data model in ER studio 19.1?

Tags: data-modeling

I am trying to generate a data dictionary in ER studio from already created logical and physical data model but not able to find anything.

I tried going to data dictionary section and create data dictionary but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the Domains in your Data Dictionary by using the Macro: [Infer](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/ERStudioDA/193/en/Sample_Macros_Installed_with_ER/Studio_Data_Architect#Modeling_Productivity_Macros)

ER/Studio Data Architect creates a domain for each unique combination of a column|attribute name and its associated datatype properties.
It doesn't **automatically** generate the other reusable dictionary objects such as Rules, Defaults, etc